# Events onKeyup and onChange not firing in plugin

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a plugin for my website. My intention is to grab some data from a website and compile it into objects.

Then I will be doing searches through these objects when text is entered into an editable span. However the `test` method doesn't appear to be called at the moment whenever I enter data. Any ideas?

```
var MarvSearch = function(elm, options) {

    this.element = elm;
    this.options = jQuery.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
    this.makes = null;
    this.models = null;
    this.init();

  }; MarvSearch.prototype = {

    init: function() {
      var $models = [], $makes = [];
      // Filter model array into objects
      $(modelItems).each(function() {
        var $num = $(this)[2].match(/\((.*)\)/)[1],
            $title = ($(this)[2].replace(/\((.*)\)/, '')).trim(),
            $entry = { 'makeID': $(this)[0], 'modelID': $(this)[1], 'title': $title, 'num': $num };
        $models.push($entry);
      });
      // Filter make select options into array
      $('#make option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() !== '')
          $makes.push({
            makeID: $(this).val(), 
            title: ($(this).text()).replace(/\((.*)\)/, '').trim(),
            num: $(this).text().match(/\((.*)\)/)[1]
          });
      });
      this.models = $models;
      this.makes = $makes;
    },
    defaults: {

    },
    attach: function() {
      var self = this;
      JQuery(this.element).bind({
        'change.MarvSearch': function(){ self.test(this.element); },
        'keyup.MarvSearch': function(){ self.test(this.element); }
      });
    },
    test: function() {
      console.log(this.element);
    }
  };
  var MarvSearch = new MarvSearch(document.getElementById('marv-search'));
```

Comment: You pass `this.element` to `test()` but fail to pick up anything up as argument(s). `console.log()` isn't clairvoyant.

Comment: `this.element` should be what is set in the initial function at the top, this appears to be the case in the attach method @Roamer-1888

Comment: Does it stop working somewhere in the code, or does it still run after `test`? but just doesn't print it out?

Comment: Fair enough if that's what you want but in that case calling `self.test(this.element)` is confusing (well it confused me). Why not `self.test()`?

Comment: Ah I get what you mean now @Roamer-1888, I have changed this to `self.test()`.

Comment: @KingReload, it doesn't appear to be executing `test` at all :S

Comment: @MartynBall but it does execute `defaults` and such?

Comment: @KingReload Turns out im an idiot, i'm not executing the attach method anywhere :/ Sorry.

Comment: @MartynBall glad it's solved xD

Comment: Presumably you found the `JQuery` typo, and you should use `.on()` not `.bind()` these days.

Comment: didn't know that, still works. I will change it to `.on()` though. Thanks

Comment: `.bind()` has been deprecated for some time. It may disappear from jQuery at some point.